# How to set default DateTime() in Laravel migrations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to achieve the functionality illustrated below:

```
$table->dateTime('time')->default(new \DateTime());
```

This exact code is failing, because

> [ErrorException] 
>      Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

The other problem is, that I feel that there should be more robust/elegant way of solving this issue. So, how to correctly set a default `DateTime` value in migrations?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is marked as duplicate. Timestamp and dateTime are similar but none of the answers tell how to set default value for `dateTime`, not for `timestamp`. To set dateTime default value you can use `Carbon`. `$table->dateTime('time')->default(\Carbon\Carbon::now());`

Comment: @Mirceac21 The challenge with that is it will set it to the actual current time at that moment. This would set it dynamically `$table->dateTime('app_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
`

Comment: @Mirceac21 thats a sooo poor approach. You want the current datetime at the moment of insertion, no at the moment the migration is declared!

Comment: @Juan @kakoma I thought that the question is about the error thrown by migration when `DateTime` is used. You are both right but it depends on the app needs what "time" to use php or mysql or a fixed date (ex: `Carbon::yesterday()`). The question is how to set default date time not current time.

Comment: You can use $table->dateTime('time')->default(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))

Comment: as in `$table->dateTime('time')->default(date("1900-1-1 00:00:00"));`. Looked a long time for this, but everything is about using current time functions

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$table->timestamp('time')->useCurrent = true;
```

See, if that helps.

*Edit*:

A better way to write the migration is

```
$table->timestamp('time')->useCurrent();
```

Comment: why use true? it's required or not?

Comment: You should be able to just call `$table->timestamp('time')->useCurrent()`. It likely does the exact same thing, but doesn't end the chain, which lets you do e.g. `$table->timestamp('time')->useCurrent()->change()`. This may be from a newer version of Laravel than the one in 2016 though.

Comment: i think @SteenSchütt 's way is more elegant....thank you... i just edit Gaurav Dave's answer for others' ease.....